# Using Cakephp, how can I get a multi-select element or checkboxes for a hasMany relationship in my scaffolded add, edit views?

Tags: php, cakephp, has-many, scaffolding

I've run through the Cakephp documentation on linking models together (creating associations), and I can get a single select dropdown in the scaffolded add and edit views by defining a $hasOne member one model and a corresponding $belongsTo in the other. Now, for a $hasMany relationship, I'm trying to get some kind of form input (either a multi-select dropdown, or checkboxes ... preferably checkboxes) in my scaffolded add and edit views that lets the user choose the associated advertisements for a given rental. But with the below code I get no mention of Advertisements in the Rental add and edit views :'( Am I missing something? Is this even possible? I've seen this done in RoR and Grails but can't get it working with CakePHP. Thanks for any help!

Rental model (app/Model/Rental.php)

```
<?php
class Rental extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Rental';             
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Agent' => array(
            'className'    => 'User',
            'foreignKey'    => 'agent_id'
        ),
        'Bedroom',
        'Landlord' => array(
            'className'    => 'Landlord',
            'foreignKey'    => 'landlord_id'
        )
    );  
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Advertisement' => array(
            'className'     => 'Advertisement',
            'foreignKey'    => 'rental_id',
            //'conditions'    => array('Comment.status' => '1'),
            'order'    => 'Advertisement.created DESC',
            'limit'        => '5',
            'dependent'=> false
        )
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );

    public function isOwnedBy($rental, $user) {
        return $this->field('id', array('id' => $rental, 'user_id' => $user)) === $rental;
    }
}
```

Rentals Controller (app/Controller/RentalsController.php)

```
<?php
class RentalsController extends AppController {
    public $scaffold;
}
```

Advertisement model (app/Model/Advertisement.php)

```
<?php
class Advertisement extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Advertisement';                   
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Rental' => array(
            'className'    => 'Rental',
            'foreignKey'    => 'rental_id'
        ),
        'Author' => array(
            'className'    => 'User',
            'foreignKey'    => 'author_id'
        )
    ); 
}
```

Advertisements Controller (app/Controller/AdvertiesementsController.php)

```
<?php
class AdvertisementsController extends AppController {
    public $scaffold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake's scaffold views don't show anything from the hasMany side of the relationship. They assume you want to pick it from the model that has the belongsTo.

Frankly, doing it as a multi-select is a little odd for this relationship, IMHO. Multi-selects are normally used for hasAndBelongsToMany relationships. If you want to do it, you'll need to do the work yourself, and not use Cake's scaffolding.

Comment: a habtm is just a hasMany and belongsTo short cut, so your comment about what they are normally used for is contradictory. Besides that you are correct, scaffolding is for RAD / prototyping. This is a bit beyond the basics that scaffolding will provide.

Comment: @dogmatic69 Yes and no... habtm is a special shortcut relationship, that hides the connecting model, and simplifies working with it. Yes, you can do it yourself with explicit models, but for simple cases that's not necessary. But that's getting into semantics and details that aren't really relevant. :)

Comment: @Utoxin - thanks, I started digging into creating the form input by hand and realized I didn't want a multi-select or checkboxes since the user could deselect (or uncheck) all options and violating my nullable constraint. I ended up just leaving the related table on the view for the hasMany and letting the create the associations in the add and edit views for the object with the belongsTo. Thanks for your help!